# How to send Tor traffic through ssh tunnel?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, anonymity, socks, torsocks

I want to use TOR in such way:

> Tor Browser --> local Socks5 proxy --> VPS (connection through ssh
>   tunnel) --> Tor Network --> Internet

Questions:

- How to setup such a connection?
- Will my ISP know that I'm using TOR? (By ISP I mean ISP of a computer where Tor Browser is installed, not ISP of VPS)
- Is it secure?

Comment: I connect socks5 to VPS using this command: ssh -D socks_port -f -C -q -N username@host

Answer (score 2):

You want to configure Tor to use an upstream proxy.

Tor Button/Onion Menu -> Network Settings -> Tick 'This computer needs to use a local proxy to access the Internet'

- Proxy Type: `SOCKS5`
- Address: `127.0.0.1`
- Port: *Enter the port number you set for `-D` here*
- Username and Password: *Leave blank*

Select "OK".

Now the Tor that Tor Browser launches will connect through the SOCKS proxy provided by SSH to reach the Tor Network.

Your ISP may still be able to see that you're using Tor if they are looking hard enough.

It's not necessarily insecure but it's potentially adding more places where an adversary could get information about traffic between you and your guard from.

As a general rule: *mo' hops, mo' problems*.